# Android database view in room

Tags: android, database-view

I have some sqlite error in database view in room :

```
@Entity(tableName = "customers")
data class Customer(@PrimaryKey val id: Int, val name : String, val add : String, val gen: 
String ="Hi")
@Entity(tableName = "gender")
data class Gender (@PrimaryKey val id:Int, val gen :String)


@DatabaseView("SELECT " +
    "customers.id, " +
    "customers.name, " +
    "customers.add, "+
    "gender.gen AS gen FROM customers " +
    "LEFT JOIN gender ON customers.id = gender.id")
data class UserDetail(
val id: Int,
val name: String,
val add :String ="",
val gen: String

)


@Dao
interface  UserDAO
{
@Query("select * from UserDetail")
suspend fun getUSers() : List<UserDetail>

@Insert
suspend fun insertCustomer(customer: Customer)


@Insert
suspend fun  insetGender(gen: Gender)
```

}

LogCat is showing this error:

> e: /Users/****/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/dexter/roompractice/UserDetail.java:7: error: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "add": syntax error)
>               public final class UserDetail {
>                            ^
>       e: > /Users/****/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/dexter/roompractice/UserDAO.java:11: error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: UserDetail)
>                   public abstract java.lang.Object getUSers(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

Answer (score 0):

`add` is a keyword. Changing it to `address` worked.